# Flex (v4.1) TLF (v.1.1) not showing embeded font

Tags: flash, flex4, embedded-fonts

I have embedded a Font in my flex app. That works on any components without problems.

```
  @font-face {
   src:url("../assets/fonts/wedtxtn.ttf");
   fontFamily: "CSSFont";
   cff: true;
  }
```

However, when I try to apply the font to my TextFlow object, it is not working. However, it does work when I use the FTE and do it my self. I debugged through the TLF and the looks like the correct FontDescription is created.

Here is the code I use to create text ([Full Source @ Pastbin](http://pastebin.com/uQy1aPv9))

```
var element:SpriteVisualElement = new SpriteVisualElement;
 element.verticalCenter = 0;
 element.horizontalCenter = 0;

// Create Text using TLF
var span:SpanElement = new SpanElement();
 span.text = "Hello World!";

var p:ParagraphElement = new ParagraphElement();
 p.addChild(span);

var tf:TextFlow = new TextFlow();
 tf.addChild(p);
 tf.fontLookup = FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF;
 tf.renderingMode = RenderingMode.CFF;
 tf.fontFamily = "CSSFont";


var textContent:Sprite = new Sprite;
 textContent.y = -50;
element.addChild(textContent);

var textController:ContainerController = new ContainerController(textContent);
 textController.verticalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.OFF;
 textController.horizontalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.OFF;

tf.flowComposer.addController(textController);
tf.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();



// Create text using FTE    
var fontDescription:FontDescription = new FontDescription("CSSFont");
 fontDescription.fontLookup = FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF;
 fontDescription.renderingMode = RenderingMode.CFF;

var format:ElementFormat = new ElementFormat(fontDescription,25);

var textElement:TextElement = new TextElement("Hello World", format);

var textBlock:TextBlock = new TextBlock(textElement);

var tl:TextLine = textBlock.createTextLine();
 tl.y = 50;

element.addChild(tl);

addElement(element);
```

Flex v4.1,
TLF v1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a bug. More informations yo can find in the [adobe forum](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/462713). There are a second link, pointing to a workaround.

BR
Frank

Comment: Thanks mate! Spent the whole day yesterday on it :(